# Can two black holes on a collision course, escape the merger?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, collision, event-horizon

Let's consider in this hypothesis that the two black holes have similar masses and approximation speed 0,99 c.

At the maximum approximation point, only their event horizons are invaded slightly. The singularities don't participate in the collision.

I wold like to know:

Can these black holes escape the merger?

If it is possible to escape, can one black hole "steal" internal content from another?

Comment: *"At the maximum approximation point, only their event horizons are invaded slightly"* Do you mean that the event horizons overlap?

Comment: @PM2Ring - Yes! Sorry, my poor english.

Comment: No, they can't escape. This question was asked recently on the Astronomy stack: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32410/16685

Comment: Here's a related question on this site: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18769/

Comment: @PM2Ring - Exactly, here; astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32410/16685  is written in detail all the content of my question, Thanks!

Comment: Once the event horizons merge that is it, they are fused. If you were following these black holes and entered before or at the merger both would present apparent horizons that would transition into a single apparent horizon. If you remain outside, the smart choice, the region the merger occurs would have lots of evolving curvature just before the merger. The two black holes would then settle down in a time period about the time it takes light to cross the distance defined by the horizon radius of the fused black hole..

Comment: @LawrenceB.Crowell - I thought that high speed could  avoid the merger.

Comment: A follow-on question: would "avoiding the merger" violate the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics?

Comment: @ safespeed: This is the horizon distance in flat spacetime, not the tortoise or delay coordinate distance or proper time.